# Is using std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN() a bad practice?

Tags: c++, nan

Have the following function that searches a query for a match and returns NaN if no match was found:

```
int64_t Foo::search(const std::string& foo, int64_t t0, ...
if {
...
}
else
  return std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::quiet_NaN();
}
```

Comment: NaN is a floating point number concept. I'm surprised that your code even compiles.

Comment: What does it return when a mach is found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<T>::quiet_NaN();` is only meaningful if `T` is a floating point type for which `std::numeric_limits<T>::has_quiet_NaN();` is true. So, no, your code is not good practise.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN

Comment: so `std::numeric_limits<int>::quiet_NaN()` would be a good practice?

Comment: @A.Fenzry: You'll find that `std::numeric_limits<int>::has_quiet_NaN()`  is `false`.

Comment: @A.Fenzry notice in the link that `quiet_NaN` just returns `0`, it'd be simpler to just return `0` directly or use `std::optional`

Comment: @A.Fenzry No `int` is not a floating point type, `float`, `double`, and `long double` are the only floating point types I think.